# Behat — возможно ли использование переменных?

Tags: php, тестирование

Есть ли способ использовать переменные в `.feature` файлах, которые при выполнении теста были бы заменены на конкретные значения?

Например

```
Scenario Outline: TEST
    Given I am on the homepage
    When I visit @website
    Then I should see @title
```

В результате при выполнении `@website` и `@title` будут заменены на заданные значения.

Механизм Scenario Outlines (плейсхолдеры) не совсем то что хотелось бы.